# Деплой бота на сервере Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku

Может кто--нибудь дать инструкцию, как развернуть бота на сервере `heroku` (написанном на `python`)? Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Официальную документацию читали? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Первым делом создайте `Git` репозиторий в папке с ботом: `git init`
- Войдите в аккаунт `Heroku`: `heroku login`
- Создайте приложение: `heroku create appname --region eu`
- Создайте файл `Procfile` с содержимым: `bot: python main.py`

  - Если бот на веб-хуках, замените `bot` на `web`. Но на бесплатном тарифе, бот будет засыпать каждые 30 минут если не будет подключений, по этому на `Heroku free` лучше держать ботов на лонг-поллинге. Но проблема с засыпанием веб приложения решается с помощью http://kaffeine.herokuapp.com/.
- Теперь нужно упаковать все зависимости проекта: `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

  - Теперь наша папка выглядит приблизительно так: `Procfile  main.py  requirements.txt`
- Коммитим изменения: `git add .` затем `git commit -m 'commit'`
- Пушим на `Heroku`: `git push heroku master`
- Запускаем бота: `heroku ps:scale bot=1`
- Смотрим логи: `heroku logs -t`

На этом всё.

Comment: Вот, https://hastebin.com/pijerirojo.py

Comment: @Midnight Вы в `Procfile` точно `bot` указали?

Comment: Нет, у меня там web написано

Comment: @Midnight А нужно `bot`

Comment: Не подскажете почему на серваке вываливается ошибка? 2018-10-23T15:06:30.166700+00:00 app[bot.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/pytho
n3.6/site-packages/aiogram/utils/exceptions.py", line 116, in detect
2018-10-23T15:06:30.166702+00:00 app[bot.1]: raise err(cls.text or description)
2018-10-23T15:06:30.166712+00:00 app[bot.1]: aiogram.utils.exceptions.Terminated
ByOtherGetUpdates: Conflict: terminated by other getupdates request; make sure t
hat only one bot instance is running

Comment: @Midnight в ошибке прямым текстом сказано что апдейты слушают более одного поллинга, убедитесь что поллинг запущен 1 раз

Comment: как это можно сделать?

Comment: @Midnight, эм, у вас скрипт запущен два или более раз, проблема не в сервере. Возможно вы локально запустили или еще что-то, я не могу знать этого

Comment: Перезалил бота, но начала вываливаться ошибка 2018-10-23T17:07:44.719611+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web
processes running" method=GET path="/" host=ccupinvest.herokuapp.com request_id=
a26d25c5-63d7-4054-aba0-1f085c2c6322 fwd="77.51.122.199" dyno= connect= service=
 status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: @Midnight опять в процфайле не бот...

Comment: в файлах ничего не менял, прописано bot

Comment: @Midnight Если до этого работало, ищите где напартачили

Comment: Извините, мне вылетает ошибка: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==304 (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==304

Answer (score 0):

В папке с проектом должны быть такие 3 файла:

**Proc**

```
web: python bot.py
```

**requirements.txt**

```
pyTelegramBotAPI==3.6.6
heroku==0.1.4
```

+ другие модули (сгенерировать этот файл можно так: `pip freeze > requirements.txt`)

**runtime.txt**

```
python-3.7.0
```

или другая версия python

Из папки, где находится проект, запускаете такие команды:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "My first commit"
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

Дополнительно рекомендую установить токен как переменную:  `heroku config:set TOKEN=7593654323:AAlkjHjhDZiWUD7Th4Dl_uPlkjpdorpoHGhgdsPVjQ` (также можно установить переменные и на сайте Хероку) и обращаться к ней из программы

```
import os
os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

Answer (score 0):

необходимо будет добавить к какому из ваших приложение относится запрос (your app name)
heroku config:set TOKEN=7593654323:AAlkjHjhDZiWUD7Th4Dl_uPlkjpdorpoHGhgdsPVjQ -a your-app-name