# Хост для web бота

Tags: python, сервер

Я написал кое-какого сетевого бота на python. Мне надо что бы он был запущен 24/7. Оставлять свой компьютер всегда включенным не очень хочется. Есть ли какие-нибудь хостинги, куда я могу пихнуть python и свои сторонние библиотеки, и чтобы это постоянно работало? Так же в моей голове есть вариант с raspberry pi и моим интернетом дома, но я думаю хостинг все же лучше. Если такие сервера существуют, то как на них ставить питон и либы, а потом все это запускать?

Comment: Ключевое слово для гугла: VDS

Comment: Мне кажется, для этого идеально подойдёт https://www.heroku.com/

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/896229/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-heroku/896235#896235

Answer (score 1):

Когда-то (года 3 назад) был бесплатный (сейчас не знаю) [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/), простые виртуалки ставь и играйся с чем хочешь. Есть Python, PHP и другие контейнеры.

Если из платных, то можно попробовать очень простой в управлении облачный сервис (хостинг) от  [DigitalOcean](https://m.do.co/c/e84370ec786c). Там самая дешевая виртуальная машина $5 в месяц и ставьте и пользуйтесь ей как хотите. Для ваших целей вам хватит наверняка.

***P.S.*** ссылка на digitalocean рефферальная, если по ней зарегистрируетесь будет вам $100 на 60 дней.